# git shows dropbox synced files as modified

Tags: git

I sync a directory with an R project among some computers using dropbox. The computers are synced. In 3 PCs (ubuntu and debian) `git status` shows no changes. In one debian all R scripts show as modified with `git status`. When I do `git diff` in all the files I see `old mode 100644 new mode 100755`

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is someone changing the permissions on the files?  That's what you're seeing in your `git diff`.

Comment: this could be it. One server has execute permission on the files. Any fix?

Comment: On the server that has executable permissions, what happens if you try to remove the executable permissions, either with `git checkout .` or `chmod -x file1 file2` ?

Comment: Git already does a great job in synchronising files across local copies, why are you using Dropbox on top of it?

Comment: The "fix" is make your files consistent, or don't work on all 3 machines together.  Why are you using both dropbox and git?  Shouldn't one of those be the thing that is used as the source?

Comment: Guys I know, but at the present time I cannot get rid of Dropbox and I have to use git. I have to use all the computers (but not simultaneously). Would git config core.filemode false do the fix?